# Merging multichannel audio tracks from Mumble with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

We record talks through Mumble and because Mumble has a nitfy multichannel feature I'd figured we could get subtitles from YouTube by uploading each track to YouTube separately with `for file in *; do ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 2 -i "$img" -i "$file" -vf scale=-1:380 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 "$file".mkv; done` I then can prepend with a eg. a `sed` shell script a *nickname* for each speaker in the automatic captions i.e. subtitles from YouTube. Works like a charm.

But *merging* those tracks with `ffmpeg` gets tricky. I use `ffmpeg -i input1.ogg -input2.ogg -i input3.ogg -i input4.ogg -input5.ogg -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a] amerge=inputs=5[aout]" -map "[aout]" -ac 2 output.ogg`

*Somehow* `ffmpeg` **shortens the resulting audio track** and I don't yet have an idea why. I tried using the longest first and last since including silent tracks made even a shorter mixdown. Here are the warnings:

> [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7f8b29f02d20] No channel layout for input 1
>
> [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7f8b29f02d20] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels

But it says

> [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7f8b29f02d20] No channel layout for input 1

even when I change the *order* of inputs.

Allthough according to Mumble's documentation the tracks should be equal length VLC media info shows different track times. **However the tracks are *not* out of sync just cut off at the end.**

I also have no idea why `ffmpeg` mentions FLAC, all the files are vorbis.

`ffmpeg -i Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-chrisaiki2.ogg -i Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-Recorder.ogg -i Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-steempowerpics.ogg  -i Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-Taconator.ogg  -i Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-fuzzynewest.ogg -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a] amerge=inputs=5[aout]" -map "[aout]" -ac 2 output5.ogg`

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.4 --enable-shared --        enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-  avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-    libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, ogg, from 'Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-   chrisaiki2.ogg':
  Duration: 00:40:01.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 86 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : libsndfile
      TITLE           : chrisaiki2
Input #1, ogg, from 'Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-Recorder.ogg':
  Duration: 00:33:57.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 86 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : libsndfile
      TITLE           : Recorder
Input #2, ogg, from 'Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-steempowerpics.ogg':
  Duration: 00:33:53.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 86 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : libsndfile
      TITLE           : steempowerpics
Input #3, ogg, from 'Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-Taconator.ogg':
  Duration: 00:35:36.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 86 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : libsndfile
      TITLE           : Taconator
Input #4, ogg, from 'Mumble-2017-09-09-16-33-18-149.210.187.155-fuzzynewest.ogg':
  Duration: 00:41:53.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30 kb/s
    Stream #4:0: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 86 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : libsndfile
      TITLE           : fuzzynewest
File 'output5.ogg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7f8b29f02d20] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7f8b29f02d20] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[flac @ 0x7f8b2b005600] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
Output #0, ogg, to 'output5.ogg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 flac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (vorbis) -> amerge:in0
  Stream #1:0 (vorbis) -> amerge:in1
  Stream #2:0 (vorbis) -> amerge:in2
  Stream #3:0 (vorbis) -> amerge:in3
  Stream #4:0 (vorbis) -> amerge:in4
  amerge -> Stream #0:0 (flac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=  100900kB time=00:33:53.94 bitrate= 406.4kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:100441kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.457024%
```

[Mumble multichannel talk on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/podcasts/comments/1v4mnk/you_know_about_mumble_right/)

Comment: Hey thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The [amerge documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) states:

> If inputs do not have the same duration, the output will stop with the
>   shortest.

[amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) may be a better filter for this case.

Comment: Thanks but [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) works only with floats (samples)? I tried [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-9) but I'm not sure about the syntax, for all examples I've seen there is a video track to _pad_ the audio against and I have just audio tracks, no video.

Comment: @Nutela amix will automatically convert the audio to float sample format  (via aresample) . By using OGG I assume you want Vorbis audio. libvorbis only supports 32-bit float planar (`fltp`), so I wouldn't think this would be a problem as it would convert to float anyway.

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard you are right. I should've checked your comment but I found essentially your answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I used `amix` in the end like this:
`ffmpeg -i input1.ogg -i input2.ogg -i input3.ogg -i inout4.ogg  -i input5.ogg  -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a] amix=inputs=5:duration=longest[aout]" -map "[aout]" -ac 2 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k output.ogg`

`ffmpeg` didn't recognize libvorbis so I had to reinstall with `brew` first: `brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvorbis`

I then used `ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 2 -i "$img" -i "$snd" -vf scale=-1:380 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 output.mkv` to upload the mixed audio tracks to YouTube.

I had merged the subtitles which were generated with YouTube as well and I just added those to the resulting video. Works like a charm.